# Rails image not running from docker-compose.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a rails application that runs on Docker. My source code have the following files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
CMD bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
   - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
 redis:
  image: redis
  command: redis-server
  ports: 
    - "6379:6379"
 sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes: 
    - .:/myapp
 web:
  build: .
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  volumes:
   - .:/myapp
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
   - db
   - redis
   - sidekiq
```

It runs normally using `docker-compose up` since I'm running this with the source code level.

Now when I build this app and push it to Dockerhub

```
docker build -t myusername/rails-app .
docker push myusername/rails-app
```

I'm expecting that I can run the rails app from an independent `docker-compose.yml` separately from the source code.

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
   - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
 redis:
  image: redis
  command: redis-server
  ports: 
    - "6379:6379"
 sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  depends_on:
    - redis
  volumes: 
    - .:/myapp
 web:
  image: myusername/rails-app:latest # <= Running the app now from the image
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  volumes:
   - .:/myapp
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
   - db
   - redis
   - sidekiq
```

The only containers running are `redis` and `db`. The `web` is looking for this

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `docker-compose.yml` file, the one that should work somewhere else without the source code, you're still having the volume mounting the local folder in the container:

```
  volumes: 
    - .:/myapp
```

Remove that from the `sidekiq` and `web` containers and it should work.

You've also kept the `build: .` for the `sidekiq` container which is useful only for the development box. Replace it with the `image` attribute, pointing to your image.

To summarise your `docker-comspose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
   - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
 redis:
  image: redis
  command: redis-server
  ports: 
    - "6379:6379"
 sidekiq:
  image: myusername/rails-app:latest
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  depends_on:
    - redis
 web:
  image: myusername/rails-app:latest # <= Running the app now from the image
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
   - db
   - redis
   - sidekiq
```

Comment: How about the sidekiq should i change also the 'build: .' it returns an error Please point Sidekiq to a Rails application or a Ruby file.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed it, `build` is useless as it's not a dev env I guess.

Comment: it shows an error when I remove the build from sidekiq "Service sidekiq has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided. "